# Windows 7 not network discoverable

Tags: windows-7, printer, network-shares

I have enabled Windows 7 network discoverable, but it does not show up.  I have shared a printer that is connected to this system.

Is there more I have to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [this How To Geek article on network sharing of a printer](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-between-windows-7-and-xp/)

If after going through these settings it still doesn't work, edit your question accordingly.

[Also something to check:](http://forums.techarena.in/networking-security/1177634.htm)

> **The firewall might be blocking.** Go to
>   start then control panel then windows
>   firewall then to exceptions then to
>   check file and printer sharing, look
>   for checkmark appear on the printer
>   host. Then Restart the printer host &
>   all client machines. Sometimes if a
>   computer is not plugged, windows file
>   and printer sharing gets messed up.